# VBA Code to save an attachment (excel file) from an Outlook email that was inside another email as an attachment

Tags: vba, outlook

I have code that saves attachments in message in a specific Outlook folder.

My script will work if the email has an attachment, but will not work if the email was sent as an attachment **with an attachment**.

In this case my emails contains other emails as attachments (from an auto-forward rule). The embedded email attachments then  contain excel files.

Please see my current [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) below:

```
Public Sub SaveOlAttachments()
  Dim isAttachment As Boolean
  Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim att As Outlook.Attachment
  Dim fsSaveFolder, sSavePathFS, ssender As String

  On Error GoTo crash

  fsSaveFolder = "C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\"
  isAttachment = False
  Set olFolder = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders("...email server...")
  Set olFolder = olFolder.Folders("Inbox")
  If olFolder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

  For Each msg In olFolder.Items
    If UCase(msg.Subject) = "TEST EMAIL WITH ATTACHMENT" Then
                    If msg.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
          While msg.Attachments.Count > 0
                sSavePathFS = fsSaveFolder & msg.Attachments(1).Filename
            msg.Attachments(1).SaveAsFile sSavePathFS
            msg.Attachments(1).Delete
            isAttachment = True
          Wend
          msg.Delete
        End If
    End If    
  Next

crash:
  If isAttachment = True Then Call findFiles(fsSaveFolder)
End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below uses this approach to work on the email as an attachment

1. Tests whether the attachment is an email message or not (if the filename ends in msg)
2. If the attachment is a message, it is saved as `"C:\temp\KillMe.msg"`.
3. `CreateItemFromTemplate` is used to access the saved file as a new message (msg2)
4. The code then processes this temporary message to strip the attachmnets to `fsSaveFolder`
5. If the attachment is not a message then it is extracted as per your current code

Note that as I didnt have your olFolder structure, Windoes version, `Outlook` variable etc I have had to add in my own file paths and Outlook folders to test. You will need to change these

```
   Sub SaveOlAttachments()

    Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim msg2 As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim att As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim strFilePath As String
    Dim strTmpMsg As String
    Dim fsSaveFolder As String

    fsSaveFolder = "C:\test\"

    'path for creating attachment msg file for stripping
    strFilePath = "C:\temp\"
    strTmpMsg = "KillMe.msg"

   'My testing done in Outlok using a "temp" folder underneath Inbox
    Set olFolder = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set olFolder = olFolder.Folders("Temp")
    If olFolder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    For Each msg In olFolder.Items
        If msg.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
        While msg.Attachments.Count > 0
        bflag = False
            If Right$(msg.Attachments(1).FileName, 3) = "msg" Then
                bflag = True
                msg.Attachments(1).SaveAsFile strFilePath & strTmpMsg
                Set msg2 = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate(strFilePath & strTmpMsg)
            End If
            If bflag Then
                sSavePathFS = fsSaveFolder & msg2.Attachments(1).FileName
                msg2.Attachments(1).SaveAsFile sSavePathFS
                msg2.Delete
            Else
                sSavePathFS = fsSaveFolder & msg.Attachments(1).FileName
                msg.Attachments(1).SaveAsFile sSavePathFS
            End If
            msg.Attachments(1).Delete
            Wend
             msg.Delete
        End If
    Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Works perfect!  The only thing I changed was: 
 
Application.CreateItemFromTemplate(strFilePath & strTmpMsg)

to 

Outlook.CreateItemFromTemplate(strFilePath & strTmpMsg)