# Extract attachments from saved .msg files using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to extract attached Excel spreadsheets from saved Outlook messages. The messages have been saved into a shared folder as .msg files.

I am struggling to get VBA to recognise the messages as files.

I am trying to get the message details in the code below as a proof of concept.

Once I have this working I can work on looping through the files and dealing with the attachments.

I have found code on this site for extracting attachments from emails still in Outlook but I do not have access to the Outlook folders and the original messages have been deleted.

```
Sub ExtractExcel()
Dim aExcel As Outlook.Attachment
Dim stFilePath As String
Dim stFileName As String
Dim stAttName As String
Dim stSaveFolder As String
Dim oEmail As Outlook.MailItem

'~~> Outlook Variables for email
Dim eSender As String, dtRecvd As String, dtSent As String
Dim sSubj As String, sMsg As String

stFilePath = "Y:\Purchasing\The Team\User Name\Supply Chain Admin - Outlook\New-Revised Orders\FW  Mail Order Daffodil.msg"
stSaveFolder = "C:\Projects\SOTD\PO_Excel"

Debug.Print stFilePath
Debug.Print stSaveFolder

oEmail = stFilePath

With oEmail 
    eSender = oEmail.SenderEmailAddress
    dtRecvd = oEmail.ReceivedTime
    dtSent = oEmail.CreationTime
    sSubj = oEmail.Subject
    sMsg = oEmail.Body

    Debug.Print eSender
    Debug.Print dtRecvd
    Debug.Print dtSent
    Debug.Print sSubj
    Debug.Print sMsg
End With

End Sub
```

I'm using Excel VBA as I am familiar with it but am happy to have any alternative strategies suggested.

Comment: Have you looked at  CreateItemFromTemplate from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890612/vba-code-to-save-an-attachment-excel-file-from-an-outlook-email-that-was-insid/7916444#7916444?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `CreateItemFromTemplate` from [VBA Code to save an attachment (excel file) from an Outlook email that was inside another email as an attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890612/vba-code-to-save-an-attachment-excel-file-from-an-outlook-email-that-was-insid/7916444#7916444) you could

- open *msg* files from `C:\temp\`
- strip all attachments to `C:\temp1\`

*code*

```
Sub SaveOlAttachments()

Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim att As Outlook.Attachment
Dim strFilePath As String
Dim strAttPath As String

    'path for creating msgs
strFilePath = "C:\temp\"
    'path for saving attachments
strAttPath = "C:\temp1\"

strFile = Dir(strFilePath & "*.msg")
Do While Len(strFile) > 0
    Set msg = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate(strFilePath & strFile)
    If msg.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
         For Each att In msg.Attachments
             att.SaveAsFile strAttPath & att.FileName
         Next
    End If
    strFile = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm getting an error on the Set msg line:  Run time error 438  "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: Fixed it! Ran the code in Outlook instead of Excel and it has worked. Thanks very much for your help :-)

Comment: You can get it running from Excel. (1) reference outlook object library (2) Add `Dim app as Outlook.Application` to your declarations (3) use 'app' instead of 'Application'.

Answer (score 2):

I have a VBS script that I use to extract all XLS* attachments form msg files saved in a folder. This script save the attachments in the same folder of msg files. I believe that can help you.

**Macro.vbs**

```
'Variables
Dim ol, fso, folderPath, destPath, f, msg, i
'Loading objects
Set ol  = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Setting MSG files path
folderPath = fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
'Setting destination path
destPath = folderPath   '* I am using the same 
WScript.Echo "==> "& folderPath
'Looping for files
For Each f In fso.GetFolder(folderPath).Files
    'Filtering only MSG files
    If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f)) = "msg" Then
        'Opening the file
        Set msg = ol.CreateItemFromTemplate(f.Path)
        'Checking if there are attachments
        If msg.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
            'Looping for attachments
            For i = 1 To msg.Attachments.Count
                'Checking if is a Excel file
                If LCase(Mid(msg.Attachments(i).FileName, InStrRev(msg.Attachments(i).FileName, ".") + 1 , 3)) = "xls" Then
                    WScript.Echo f.Name &" -> "& msg.Attachments(i).FileName
                    'Saving the attachment
                    msg.Attachments(i).SaveAsFile destPath &"\"& msg.Attachments(i).FileName
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End If
Next
MsgBox "Anexos extraidos com sucesso!"
```

To execute use "cscript c:\temp\msg_files\Macro.vbs" in command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

I changed this code so that you can extract attachments from Excel instead of outlook.

Don't forget to reference the Outlook Library, otherwise you will get the error

```
Sub SaveOlAttachments()

Dim app As Outlook.Application
Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim att As Outlook.Attachment
Dim strFilePath As String
Dim strAttPath As String

Set app = New Outlook.Application

'path for creating msgs
strFilePath = "C:\Users\New folder\"

'path for saving attachments
strAttPath = "C:\Users\Extract\"

strFile = Dir(strFilePath & "*.msg")

Do While Len(strFile) > 0
    Set msg = app.CreateItemFromTemplate(strFilePath & strFile)
    If msg.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
         For Each att In msg.Attachments
             att.SaveAsFile strAttPath & att.Filename
         Next
    End If
    strFile = Dir
Loop

MsgBox "Task Completed", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Namespace.OpenSharedItem`. Do not use `CreateItemFromTemplate` - it wipes out many properties (such as sender and receiver related properties).

Comment: Not sure why that would be an issue given OP wants to strip attachments?

Comment: It would be an issue for other people who are reading this thread if they want to extract properties other than attachments.